# How prevent date regeneration of the java code if the thrift file haven't been changed?

Tags: java, thrift

I have a thrift file - `api.thrift`. The Java generator creates a date stamp on the generated Java file. Example:

```
@Generated(value = "Autogenerated by Thrift Compiler (0.9.2)", date = "2015-9-4")
```

The problem is that the date is that the files are regenerated each time with a the generation date - even if the thrift file haven't changed.

**How can I prevent the date generation?** (or the complete code generation if the thrift file haven't been changed?)

Comment: BTW, no date stamp on JS generated files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[THRIFT-3220](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-3220) implements a solution for exactly this issue. Implemented in trunk and the forthcoming 0.9.3 release.

Usage:

```
  thrift -gen java:generated_annotations=suppress  yourfile.thrift
```

Comment: Great, so how do I use the `generated_annotations` directive? In the thrift file? Something like `generated_annotations=undated` in a new line?